# Stuck on Comparator<T>

Tags: java

this is my very first post.  This is for Java 7.

Can someone please tell me why I'm not able to access "first.a" in the CompareIpaddress class?  (I'm not sure why SOF won't allow me to post this unless I type more stuff...)  Is this enough filler?

Thanks,
Gordon

```
  import java.util.Comparator; 
  import java.util.*; // just in case i need it.
  import java.util.TreeSet;

  public class CompareIpaddress <IPaddress >implements Comparator<IPaddress>
  {
     /************************************************compare()**/
     public int compare (IPaddress first, IPaddress second)
     {
       if( first.a < second.a )
       {   
          return -1;
       }
     }
  }

  import java.util.Comparator;
  import java.util.*;
  import java.util.TreeSet;

  public class IPaddress
  {
     public int a, b, c, d;

     IPaddress (int a, int b, int c, int d)
     {
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
        this.c=c;
        this.d=d;
     }

     public int getA()
     {
        return a;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public class CompareIpaddress <IPaddress >implements Comparator<IPaddress>
```

You make `IPaddress` a type parameter of `CompareIpaddress`, so that is any type, not the class of the same name.

Since not every class has an accessible member `a`, the compiler cannot find the symbol.

```
public class CompareIpaddress implements Comparator<IPaddress>
```

is the correct way.

(You need to return a value also for the other cases, but I suppose you have just cut that down for the question.)

Comment: To put it in other words. By writing public class CompareIpaddress<IPaddress> he redefined the meaning of IPaddress in that specific class to be a generic parameter instead.

Comment: I changed it to this, and it fixed the first.a, however, it affected             TreeSet ts = TreeSet(Comparator <? super IPaddress> compare);

Comment: Here's my full code:  (I really have a hard time with this editor!!! it won't let me hit return to insert code.)

Comment: You could ask a new question about that, @Gordon415. It would change this one too much, I think, to add the new code, and I am not overly optimistic that your problem could be diagnosed without seeing the code.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the type parameter `IPaddress` in `public class CompareIpaddress <IPaddress> implements Comparator<IPaddress>`. By this you are shadowing the class name `IPaddress` with a type parameter.

You in fact don't need a type parameter here at all.
Change it to `public class CompareIpaddress implements Comparator<IPaddress>` and everything is fine.

Comment: Sebastian, how do you know when I need to use the type parameter.. (I'm having a very hard time editing my reply in this window..)  How do you know when I need  public class CompareIpaddress implements Comparator<IPaddress>  verses  public class CompareIpaddress <IPaddress> implements Comparator<IPaddress>     I suppose I don't need to have a type parameter because I'm only going to one type of generics, and that is that it will always be an IPaddress object?

Answer (score 1):

```
 public int compare (IPaddress first, IPaddress second)
 {
   if( first.a < second.a )
   {   
      return -1;
   }
 }
```

This code won't compile, because when you declare a method that returns a type `int`, it must **ALWAYS** return a type `int`. At the moment, it only returns a value if `first.a` is less than `second.a`. You should add in some other cases, to cover every eventuality:

```
if(first.a < second.a) 
{
    return -1;
}
else if(first.a > second.a)
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Agreed. I didn't delete because it supplements the other answers quite well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
public class CompareIpaddress implements Comparator<IPaddress>
```

as you don't really need a type parameter

If you use a IDE, you probably will get some warning of this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to. I think that your error is that you dont have an alternate return statement. Try instead of the if in the compare method to just use the code:

```
 public int compare (IPaddress first, IPaddress second)
 {
   return first.a - second.a; //Returns 0 if equal.
 }
```